# Progress bar from another layout and show it in another layout

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Currently i am in Tabbed Activity tab and i have set friends_fragment in layout! my friends_fragment contains a recycler view. Another layout named as activity_friends which is set as viewHolder for that recycler view. i have progress bar in activity_friends and want to access it from that tabbed activity. how i can do that

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);


            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            DialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_friends, null);
            bar=(ProgressBar)DialogView.findViewById(R.id.pBar);

            bar.setVisibility(DialogView.INVISIBLE); // or VISIBLE

            return view;


        }
```

Friends_Fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.umairahmed.tracknotesapp.Friends">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/friendRecyclerView"
      >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_friends

```
<ProgressBar
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
     android:id="@+id/pBar"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userImg"
     android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/userImg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

update fragment_activity layout to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.umairahmed.tracknotesapp.Friends">

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/friendRecyclerView">

           </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

     </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and Fragment_activity java class to

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);


        FrameLayout MainFrame = (MainFrame)view.findViewById(R.id.MainFrame);
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        DialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_friends, null);
        MainFrame.addView(DialogView);

        bar=(ProgressBar)DialogView.findViewById(R.id.pBar);

        bar.setVisibility(DialogView.INVISIBLE); // or VISIBLE

        return view;


    }
```

Comment: its saying me to add qualifier or method, it isn't allowing me to use addView() with view